# How do I take text input commands in the following piece of code?

Tags: python, python-3.x, tkinter

I am building a Python GUI where I can enter commands such as play music, pictures etc. which will be executed. I have not yet started working on OS codes. 
How do I take user commands using the text box?

or, simply:

How do I make this text box a command box?

```
from tkinter import *
import quotes              #Imported external module having quotations
my_quote = "Random quote."

root = None
textSpace = None
texter = None

def textBox(parent):        #creates a text box
    global textSpace
    textSpace = Entry(parent)
    textSpace.place(x = 205, y = 190, width = "200")

def text_input():
    global texter
    texter = textSpace.get()
    print("Text entered:", texter)

def quotes():               #Random quote at bottom of window
    global root
    quote_text = Label(root, text = my_quote, font = ("papyrus", 7, 
    "italic"), 
    bg = "light sky blue")
    quote_text.pack(side = "bottom")

def main_win():             #This is the main window
    global root
    global textSpace
    input = textBox         #I am not sure if this is correct
    user_command = input
    root = Tk()             #We have to initiate the window right
    root.title("Greetings")
    root.configure(bg = "light sky blue")
    root.geometry("600x350")
    head_text = Label(root, text = "PEWDS", font=("Comic Sans MS", 36, 
    "bold"), bg = "light sky blue", fg = "purple")
    head_text.pack(side = "top")
    sub_text = Label(root, text = "Enter your command below.", font=("MS 
    sans serif", 20, "italic"), bg = "light sky blue", fg = "alice blue")
    sub_text.pack()
    quotes()
    go_button = Button(text = "GO", command = text_input)
    go_button.place(x=285, y=230)
    go_button.configure(bg = "cadetblue")
    textBox(root)
    root.mainloop


main_win()
```

Comment: I think what you want is a CLI (Command Line Interface). search around this for python and if you had problem come and ask. question is vague

Comment: use raw_input() to get the data and don't declare global variables multiples times

Comment: this is not a good design for a CLI. I really suggest you go around and search about this. there are a lot of CLI tools that you can use to create a simple simple or multicommand CLI ! I think what you really need is to research more about this.

Comment: for example, you mentioned GUI  (Graphical User Inteface) in your question. where GUI is completely different than what you want. these kind of things have design patterns implemented in themselves so that later you can easily maintain you code. add new command without changing any of code. this is really important that you first learn about the thing that you want to do

Comment: I am actually an amateur right now.. Thanks for suggesting CLI .. :)

Comment: @AkshayKathpal in this case the OP should use `input()` not `raw_input()` due to the fact the OP is using python 3.

Comment: Quick question. Are any of the commands you want to use going to be multi line? Or can everything be done in one line of the text box?

Comment: @SierraMountainTech i am using 2.7 so if i need numbers I just change them to int